# Android: Is it possible to display video thumbnails?

Tags: android

I created a video recording application with library dialog. The library dialog displays the list of recorded videos where each item consists of icon, video title, tags and location information the following way:

[image]

Does anyone know whether it is possible to replace icons with video thumbnails (single frame preview)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If you are using API 2.0 or newer this will work.

```
int id = **"The Video's ID"**
ImageView iv = (ImageView ) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imagePreview);
ContentResolver crThumb = getContentResolver();
BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 1;
Bitmap curThumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(crThumb, id, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, options);
iv.setImageBitmap(curThumb);
```

Comment: You can query the MediaStore for Videos on the phone. The "id" is just one of the pieces of information you query. See more about the MediaStore at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Video.html

Comment: Use Glide, it is really easy

Comment: if you get `null` when passing in a file ID, make sure the value is a long, and not a string.

Answer (score 98):

if you don't or cannot go through cursor and if you have only paths or File objects, you can use since API level 8 (2.2)
    public static Bitmap createVideoThumbnail (String filePath, int kind)

[Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html#createVideoThumbnail%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

The following code runs perfectly:

```
Bitmap bMap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(file.getAbsolutePath(), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
```

Comment: `'createVideoThumbnail(java.lang.String, int)'` is deprecated

Answer (score 43):

Using the class:

```
import android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails;
```

We can get two preview thumbnail sizes from the video:

#### `Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND` for 96 x 96

#### `Thumbnails.MINI_KIND` for 512 x 384 px

This is a code example:

```
String filePath = "/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/my_video.mp4"; //change the location of your file!

ImageView imageview_mini = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_mini);
ImageView imageview_micro = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_micro);

Bitmap bmThumbnail;

//MICRO_KIND, size: 96 x 96 thumbnail
bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath, Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
imageview_micro.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);
     
// MINI_KIND, size: 512 x 384 thumbnail 
bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath, Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
imageview_mini.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);
```

Comment: If I have a link like so for the filepath would this not work, because I am trying to set it to an imageview and it is not showing anything... this is the file path "http:/ /unknown.com/v3-1aox9d1 .mp4" being a real domain obviously, but is that path not thumbnail-able?

Comment: To use ThumbnailUtils class, you have to save the file to disk  the use the method:  ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail( )

Answer (score 28):

I really suggest you to use the **Glide** library. It's among the most efficient way to generate and display a video thumbnail for a local video file.

Just add this line to your gradle file :

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

And it will become as simple as :

```
String filePath = "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/example_video.mp4";

Glide  
    .with( context )
    .load( Uri.fromFile( new File( filePath ) ) )
    .into( imageViewGifAsBitmap );
```

You can find more informations here : https://futurestud.io/blog/glide-displaying-gifs-and-videos

Cheers !

Comment: Glide only works with local videos , not Url videos , isnt there a simple way for this

Comment: Some devices does not display thumbnail image for local videos

Answer (score 22):

Currently I Use following code :

```
Bitmap bMap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(file.getAbsolutePath(), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
```

But I found better solution with [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library with following code ( It also cache your image and have better performance than previous approach )

```
Glide.with(context)
                .load(uri)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_video_place_holder)
                .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this it's working for me

```
RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
 Glide.with(getContext())
      .load("video_url")
      .apply(requestOptions)
      .thumbnail(Glide.with(getContext()).load("video_url"))
      .into("yourimageview");
```

Answer (score 6):

This solution will work for any version of Android. It has proven to work in 1.5 and 2.2 This is not another "This is for Android 2.0+" solution. I found this through an email message board collection page and cannot find the original link. All credit goes to the original poster.

In your app you would use this by calling:

```
Bitmap bm = getVideoFrame(VideoStringUri);
```

Somewhere in it's own function (outside the OnCreate, ect), you would need:

```
private Bitmap getVideoFrame(String uri) {
        MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        try {
            retriever.setMode(MediaMetadataRetriever.MODE_CAPTURE_FRAME_ONLY);
            retriever.setDataSource(uri);
            return retriever.captureFrame();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                retriever.release();
            } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

In your src folder, you need a new subdirectory android/media which will house the class (copied from the android source itself) which allows you to use this function. This part should not be changed, renamed, or placed anywhere else. MediaMetadataRetriever.java needs to be under android.media in your source folder for this all to work.

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2008 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package android.media;

import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;

/**
 * MediaMetadataRetriever class provides a unified interface for retrieving
 * frame and meta data from an input media file. {@hide}
 */
public class MediaMetadataRetriever {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("media_jni");
        native_init();
    }

    // The field below is accessed by native methods
    private int mNativeContext;

    public MediaMetadataRetriever() {
        native_setup();
    }

    /**
     * Call this method before setDataSource() so that the mode becomes
     * effective for subsequent operations. This method can be called only once
     * at the beginning if the intended mode of operation for a
     * MediaMetadataRetriever object remains the same for its whole lifetime,
     * and thus it is unnecessary to call this method each time setDataSource()
     * is called. If this is not never called (which is allowed), by default the
     * intended mode of operation is to both capture frame and retrieve meta
     * data (i.e., MODE_GET_METADATA_ONLY | MODE_CAPTURE_FRAME_ONLY). Often,
     * this may not be what one wants, since doing this has negative performance
     * impact on execution time of a call to setDataSource(), since both types
     * of operations may be time consuming.
     * 
     * @param mode
     *            The intended mode of operation. Can be any combination of
     *            MODE_GET_METADATA_ONLY and MODE_CAPTURE_FRAME_ONLY: 1.
     *            MODE_GET_METADATA_ONLY & MODE_CAPTURE_FRAME_ONLY: For neither
     *            frame capture nor meta data retrieval 2.
     *            MODE_GET_METADATA_ONLY: For meta data retrieval only 3.
     *            MODE_CAPTURE_FRAME_ONLY: For frame capture only 4.
     *            MODE_GET_METADATA_ONLY | MODE_CAPTURE_FRAME_ONLY: For both
     *            frame capture and meta data retrieval
     */
    public native void setMode(int mode);

    /**
     * @return the current mode of operation. A negative return value indicates
     *         some runtime error has occurred.
     */
    public native int getMode();

    /**
     * Sets the data source (file pathname) to use. Call this method before the
     * rest of the methods in this class. This method may be time-consuming.
     * 
     * @param path
     *            The path of the input media file.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             If the path is invalid.
     */
    public native void setDataSource(String path)
            throws IllegalArgumentException;

    /**
     * Sets the data source (FileDescriptor) to use. It is the caller's
     * responsibility to close the file descriptor. It is safe to do so as soon
     * as this call returns. Call this method before the rest of the methods in
     * this class. This method may be time-consuming.
     * 
     * @param fd
     *            the FileDescriptor for the file you want to play
     * @param offset
     *            the offset into the file where the data to be played starts,
     *            in bytes. It must be non-negative
     * @param length
     *            the length in bytes of the data to be played. It must be
     *            non-negative.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             if the arguments are invalid
     */
    public native void setDataSource(FileDescriptor fd, long offset, long length)
            throws IllegalArgumentException;

    /**
     * Sets the data source (FileDescriptor) to use. It is the caller's
     * responsibility to close the file descriptor. It is safe to do so as soon
     * as this call returns. Call this method before the rest of the methods in
     * this class. This method may be time-consuming.
     * 
     * @param fd
     *            the FileDescriptor for the file you want to play
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             if the FileDescriptor is invalid
     */
    public void setDataSource(FileDescriptor fd)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {
        // intentionally less than LONG_MAX
        setDataSource(fd, 0, 0x7ffffffffffffffL);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the data source as a content Uri. Call this method before the rest
     * of the methods in this class. This method may be time-consuming.
     * 
     * @param context
     *            the Context to use when resolving the Uri
     * @param uri
     *            the Content URI of the data you want to play
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             if the Uri is invalid
     * @throws SecurityException
     *             if the Uri cannot be used due to lack of permission.
     */
    public void setDataSource(Context context, Uri uri)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException {
        if (uri == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        String scheme = uri.getScheme();
        if (scheme == null || scheme.equals("file")) {
            setDataSource(uri.getPath());
            return;
        }

        AssetFileDescriptor fd = null;
        try {
            ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
            try {
                fd = resolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            if (fd == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            FileDescriptor descriptor = fd.getFileDescriptor();
            if (!descriptor.valid()) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            // Note: using getDeclaredLength so that our behavior is the same
            // as previous versions when the content provider is returning
            // a full file.
            if (fd.getDeclaredLength() < 0) {
                setDataSource(descriptor);
            } else {
                setDataSource(descriptor, fd.getStartOffset(),
                        fd.getDeclaredLength());
            }
            return;
        } catch (SecurityException ex) {
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fd != null) {
                    fd.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ioEx) {
            }
        }
        setDataSource(uri.toString());
    }

    /**
     * Call this method after setDataSource(). This method retrieves the meta
     * data value associated with the keyCode.
     * 
     * The keyCode currently supported is listed below as METADATA_XXX
     * constants. With any other value, it returns a null pointer.
     * 
     * @param keyCode
     *            One of the constants listed below at the end of the class.
     * @return The meta data value associate with the given keyCode on success;
     *         null on failure.
     */
    public native String extractMetadata(int keyCode);

    /**
     * Call this method after setDataSource(). This method finds a
     * representative frame if successful and returns it as a bitmap. This is
     * useful for generating a thumbnail for an input media source.
     * 
     * @return A Bitmap containing a representative video frame, which can be
     *         null, if such a frame cannot be retrieved.
     */
    public native Bitmap captureFrame();

    /**
     * Call this method after setDataSource(). This method finds the optional
     * graphic or album art associated (embedded or external url linked) the
     * related data source.
     * 
     * @return null if no such graphic is found.
     */
    public native byte[] extractAlbumArt();

    /**
     * Call it when one is done with the object. This method releases the memory
     * allocated internally.
     */
    public native void release();

    private native void native_setup();

    private static native void native_init();

    private native final void native_finalize();

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        try {
            native_finalize();
        } finally {
            super.finalize();
        }
    }

    public static final int MODE_GET_METADATA_ONLY = 0x01;
    public static final int MODE_CAPTURE_FRAME_ONLY = 0x02;

    /*
     * Do not change these values without updating their counterparts in
     * include/media/mediametadataretriever.h!
     */
    public static final int METADATA_KEY_CD_TRACK_NUMBER = 0;
    public static final int METADATA_KEY_ALBUM = 1;
    public static final int METADATA_KEY_ARTIST = 2;
    public static final int METADATA_KEY_AUTHOR = 3;
    public static final int METADATA_KEY_COMPOSER = 4;
    public static final int METADATA_KEY_DATE = 5;
    public static final int METADATA_KEY_GENRE = 6;
    public static final int METADATA_KEY_TITLE = 7;
    public static final int METADATA_KEY_YEAR = 8;
    public static final int METADATA_KEY_DURATION = 9;
    public static final int METADATA_KEY_NUM_TRACKS = 10;
    public static final int METADATA_KEY_IS_DRM_CRIPPLED = 11;
    public static final int METADATA_KEY_CODEC = 12;
    public static final int METADATA_KEY_RATING = 13;
    public static final int METADATA_KEY_COMMENT = 14;
    public static final int METADATA_KEY_COPYRIGHT = 15;
    public static final int METADATA_KEY_BIT_RATE = 16;
    public static final int METADATA_KEY_FRAME_RATE = 17;
    public static final int METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_FORMAT = 18;
    public static final int METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT = 19;
    public static final int METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH = 20;
    public static final int METADATA_KEY_WRITER = 21;
    public static final int METADATA_KEY_MIMETYPE = 22;
    public static final int METADATA_KEY_DISCNUMBER = 23;
    public static final int METADATA_KEY_ALBUMARTIST = 24;
    // Add more here...
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.. error at System.loadLibrary("media_jni");

Comment: `MediaMetadataRetriever` is supported from API level 10

Comment: The MediaMetadataRetriever is the second code block. It is present to allow APIs before 10 (which was not available at the time of writing) to access the code from the application instead of the system. Native system calls are possible, but you will need a rough understanding of the system to use them. It sounds like a lot of the issue is improperly implementing the source provided.

Comment: The libmedia_jni.so file is required to use it

Comment: @berserk libmedia_jni.so is a default system library, called by System.loadLibrary("media_jni");

Answer (score 5):

Android 1.5 and 1.6 do not offer this thumbnails, but 2.0 does, as seen on [the official release notes](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.0.html#api-changes):

> Media
>
> - MediaScanner now generates thumbnails for all images when they are inserted into MediaStore.
> - New Thumbnail API for retrieving image and video thumbnails on demand.

Answer (score 4):

I am answering this question late but hope it will help the other candidate facing same problem.

I have used two methods to load thumbnail for videos list the first was

```
    Bitmap bmThumbnail;
    bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(FILE_PATH
                    + videoList.get(position),
            MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);

    if (bmThumbnail != null) {
        Log.d("VideoAdapter","video thumbnail found");
        holder.imgVideo.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);
    } else {
        Log.d("VideoAdapter","video thumbnail not found");
    }
```

its look good but there was a problem with this solution because when i scroll video list it will freeze some time due to its large processing.

so after this i found another solution which works perfectly by using Glide Library.

```
 Glide
            .with( mContext )
            .load( Uri.fromFile( new File( FILE_PATH+videoList.get(position) ) ) )
            .into( holder.imgVideo );
```

I recommended the later solution for showing thumbnail with video list .
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question with an accepted answer but I want to post my answer in case somebody is searching for this:

so when I wanted to only use `Uri` so I did this:

```
val mmr = MediaMetadataRetriever()
mmr.setDataSource(videoUri)
val thummbnailBitmap = mmr.frameAtTime
imageView.setImageBitmap(thummbnailBitmap)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Glide has a WiFi problem**

I was loading the thumbnail of the video using Glide. The video can be either local or Cloud in recyclerview. Sometime GLide would not display thumbnails of video. **If I turn the wifi off the thumbnail would load.** To Fix this problem

I created two Glide objects in recyclerview

```
Glide.with(binding.img.context)
```

With Context of different View

```
Glide.with(binding.parent.context)
```

using If(condition) one loads local thumbs of video And other loads thumbnail from https urls.

**In this way the problem of Glide was solved. version used 4.14.0. It didn't work correctly with 4.16.0**

Answer (score -4):

**This is code for live Video thumbnail.**

```
public class LoadVideoThumbnail extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Bitmap>{

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {try {

            String mMediaPath = "http://commonsware.com/misc/test2.3gp";
            Log.e("TEST Chirag","<< thumbnail doInBackground"+ mMediaPath);
            FileOutputStream out;
            File land=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile()
                            +"/portland.jpg");

                Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(mMediaPath, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
                        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                        out=new  FileOutputStream(land.getPath());
                        out.write(byteArray);
                        out.close();
                 return bitmap;

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return null;
            }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if(result != null){
                 ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setImageBitmap(result);
            }
            Log.e("TEST Chirag","====> End");
        }

    }
```

Comment: i get null at `Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(mMediaPath, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);` Note that all paramters is  set

Comment: null value at Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(mMediaPath, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);