# Is there any api which generates a Thumbnail image from an inputstream which is a video file

Tags: android

Is there any api on android which generates a Thumbnail image from an inputstream which is a video file?

Thank you.

Comment: did you found any solution? it will be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I would be using `MediaMetadataRetriever` class. For more info, take a look at the source code:

Java reference

- `frameworks\base\media\java\android\media\MediaMetadataRetriever.java`

native reference:

- `frameworks\base\include\media\mediametadataretriever.h`

Comment: MediaMetadataRetriever is part of the framework/base classes, which are "Core Android app framework libraries", and not part of the public APIs. As with iPhone SDK, this may result in problems, if Google changes the internal implementation in future releases.

Still, video thumbnail generation seems to be non-trivial in Android: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334694/android-is-it-possible-to-display-video-thumbnails