# Can't get a video thumbnail in Android 2.0+

Tags: android, video, bitmap, thumbnails

I tried to create a video thumbnail as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334694/android-is-it-possible-to-display-video-thumbnails/2349063#2349063).
I also read the reference [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.html).

In my app I first let the user choose a video with:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).setType("video/*"), ACTIVITY_PICKVIDEO);
```

Then I determine the video ID with:

```
fileID = Integer.parseInt(contentUri.getLastPathSegment());
```

So, the video `content://media/external/video/media/5` would have the ID 5.

Then I try to get the thumbnail bitmap with:

```
ContentResolver crThumb = getContentResolver();
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 1;
Bitmap curThumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(crThumb, fileID, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, options);
```

There's no exception thrown but the bitmap has a width and height of -1.
I'm not sure if the ID needed in `getThubnail()` is actually the ID that I determined above.

Does anyone know of a working example how to get the thumbnail bitmap if you have the content Uri?

Interestingly (maybe so) I get null when trying with `MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND` as thumbnail size and an `IllegalArgumentException ("Unsupported kind: 2")` when I try `FULL_SCREEN_KIND`.

I'm using a Motorola Milestone with Android 2.1.

**EDIT:**
I also tried getting the ID with querying for the BaseColumns._ID but it turns out to be the same as in the Uri (in the given example the _ID is 5).

Answer (score 10):

for getting video id try this

```
String[] proj = {
    MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
    MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA
};
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
                                    proj, MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME+"=?",new String[] {"name.mp4"}, null);
cursor.moveToFirst()
fileid = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID));
```

for getting thumbnail :

```
ContentResolver crThumb = getContentResolver();
Bitmap curThumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(crThumb,fileid, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, options);
iv2.setImageBitmap(curThumb);
```

here iv2 is imageview and name.mp4 will represent your file name

Comment: @Manuel : use this function android.media.ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(     path,MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND ); here path is file path using this you can get thumbnail of particular one video