# Android get specific frames from video/while filming video

Tags: java, android, image, video, extract

My app is filming a video from which i need to get specific frames. Is it possible to save specific frames while taking the video or even after saving the video? how?

EDIT: Another option is to take several pictures in a row with no video(moving the camera and taking a picture every second)
is this possible?

Comment: I've been working on this for a couple months. There doesn't seem to be any support for Frame by Frame seeking. You can only get the keyframes. VideoView.seekTo(int) is how you do it

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to save specific frames while taking the video or even after saving the video? how?

The MediaMetadataRetriever class has a function called [`getFrameAtTime()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#getFrameAtTime%28long%29). I think this works only after saving the file. You will only get key frames.

Comment: MediaMetadataRetriever is only available from version 10 :-(

Comment: @JonathonHorsman How about [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334694/android-is-it-possible-to-display-video-thumbnails/2349063#2349063)