# Android: Is there a way we can get the thumbnail of the web video from the URL

Tags: java, android, url, thumbnails

I know I can get the thumbnail for youtube URLs. But There are tons and tons of video streaming in the web. How can we get the thumbnail of the web Video URL. Any ideas guys.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334694/android-is-it-possible-to-display-video-thumbnails/2349063#2349063) shows how to create thumbnails for local videos.

P.S. Wonder how Facebook does that.

Comment: There is a youtube api, if you look it up. However; it is dependent on how the web content is exposed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every video streaming site has its own way of storing thumbs, most of them support it, check for example youtube

http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/{VIDEO ID HERE}/hqdefault.jpg

This will return the thumb of the specific video, this could happen but with another call on most streaming video providers, facebook doesn't do that magically, it just supports most of them because facebook knows the way they show thumbs.

Comment: Thanks Spiros. This works only for youtube. For youtube even http://img.youtube.com/vi/[VIDEO_ID]/0.jpg works we can vary with 1,2,3.jpg... I'm looking for other websites like veoh.com, metacafe, google video etc...

Comment: As i said, each one implements its own way, a quick google search for "metacafe api thumbnail" takes me here : http://help.metacafe.com/?page_id=201 . Search each services' api, if facebook supports it, it should be easy to find out how :)