# Android: video files have black thumbnails

Tags: android, video, thumbnails

I have to write a program where all the videos store in my device to be shown with thumbnails.
i am able to list them all but most of them are coming with black thumbnail while in gallery application those shows perfectly.

please help me!
what i have tried is

```
MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(mContex.getContentResolver(), id, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
```

or

```
ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND)
```

Comment: For `ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail()`, you should provide path to video file, _e.g._ `"/sdcard/Video/myfile.mp4"`, and not a **uri**.

Comment: @AlexCohn Cohn that is file only the variable name is uri:( eddited my question!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some video files (e.g. **mp4**s that can be downloaded from YouTube) have few black frames in the beginning, and this is what you will see with `ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail()`.

You can use [MediaMetadataRetriever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html) class to extract frames from the file at some offset from time=0. To get the best results you, should use [getFrameAtTime(t, OPTION_NEXT_SYNC)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#getFrameAtTime%28long,%20int%29) and iterate through time **t** to find a non-trivial thumbnail. You can try the steps of 500000 (half second).

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code. Its Working For Me. [From](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334694/android-is-it-possible-to-display-video-thumbnails)

```
    int id = **"The Video's ID"**
    ImageView iv = (ImageView ) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imagePreview);
    ContentResolver crThumb = getContentResolver();
    BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 1;
    Bitmap curThumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(crThumb, id, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, options);
    iv.setImageBitmap(curThumb);


If It is not working Use This  

Bitmap bmThumbnail;
        bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videoFileList[position], Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
```

Comment: Bitmap bmThumbnail;
        bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videoFileList[position], Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);

Comment: this too. i wrote in my question what i have already tried actually some of the videos showing their thumbs but some are coming black.