# Creating thumbnail from video file returns null bitmap

Tags: android, android-camera, video-thumbnails

I send an intent to launch the video camera

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    if(pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){
            Intent video = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
            File tempDir= new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                      Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "BCA");
            if(!tempDir.exists())
            {
                if(!tempDir.mkdir()){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please check SD card! Image shot is impossible!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",Locale.US).format(new Date());
                File mediaFile = new File(tempDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "VIDEO_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
                Uri videoUri = Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
                video.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, videoUri);
                video.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
                startActivityForResult(video, VIDEO_REQUEST);

    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "This device does not have a rear facing camera",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

i take a video and it gets store correctly, When the `onActivityResult` get fired I use the intent to get the `uri` where its stored to create the bitmap

this is an example of the uri `file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/BCA/VIDEO_20131227_145043.mp4`

```
 Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(intent.getDataString(), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
```

but the bitmap is null everytime. So since the docs say `May return null if the video is corrupt or the format is not supported` I check the video in the directory and it plays fine plus its a `.mp4` file which is supported so what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hi, I hope you solved this. Please share how. Me too facing the same issue

Answer (score 4):

You can try [MediaMetadataRetriever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html) or [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever). Here is an example:

```
FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource(intent.getDataString());
Bitmap b = mmr.getFrameAtTime();
mmr.release();
```

Answer (score 3):

As I remember, argument `filePath` from [createVideoThumbnail](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html#createVideoThumbnail%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) should be a classic filepath, not `URI`.

```
...

Uri videoUri = intent.getData();
final String realFilePath = getRealPathFromUri();
Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(realFilePath, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
...

public String getRealPathFromURI(final Uri contentURI) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
        return contentURI.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
        if ( idx == -1 ) {
            return contentURI.getPath();
        }
        String rvalue =  cursor.getString(idx);
        cursor.close();
        return rvalue;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Based on the source code of `createVideoThumbnail`, I created another implementation:

```
public static Bitmap createVideoThumbnail(Context context, Uri uri, int kind) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    try {
        retriever.setMode(MediaMetadataRetriever.MODE_CAPTURE_FRAME_ONLY);
        retriever.setDataSource(context, uri);
        bitmap = retriever.captureFrame();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        // Assume this is a corrupt video file
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        // Assume this is a corrupt video file.
    } finally {
        try {
            retriever.release();
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            // Ignore failures while cleaning up.
        }
    }
    if (kind == Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND && bitmap != null) {
        bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bitmap,
                ThumbnailUtils.TARGET_SIZE_MICRO_THUMBNAIL,
                ThumbnailUtils.TARGET_SIZE_MICRO_THUMBNAIL,
                ThumbnailUtils.OPTIONS_RECYCLE_INPUT);
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: I found out that if I dont give it a path to where I want to save the video I get back a `ContentProvider Uri` where I can then use this method to get the thumbnail `MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getContentResolver(), id, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, options);` but I want to specify the path so that my users can find the videos easily

Answer (score 1):

Use this file "mediaFile" and convert it into URI

```
      Uri uri=Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
```

Then  pass that URI in the below method. This is working fine at my side.

```
Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(uri.getPath(), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem and solved it this way:

1. Create [FileUtils](https://gist.github.com/AmirHadifar/11a591ed8c1add1e0f68) Class which find path of file for you (I can't find reference of the class so I created a gist)

   ```
   String correctedUri = FileUtils.getPath(mContext, Uri.parse(localUri));
   ```
2. Use following code

   ```
   Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(correctedUri, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
   ```

**EDITED :**
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334694/android-is-it-possible-to-display-video-thumbnails/34082262#34082262) solution it has better performance and easier.