# How to create thumbnails for videos from sd card.?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I'm new to android development, and I'm listing all videos from storage(my mobile) and want to create thumbnail display in custom `ListView`.
 **My problem is when creating the thumbnail it's taking time, how to solve this ? please help me out.**

below code is to create the thumbnail

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.video_list);

    ListView videolist=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.video_list);
    ArrayList<String> videoName = new ArrayList<>();
    final ArrayList<String> videoPath = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Bitmap> videoThumbnail = new ArrayList<>();

    String selection =MediaStore.Video.Media._ID;
    String[] columns = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME};

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            columns, selection, null, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()){

        Bitmap bmThumbnail;
        bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(String.valueOf(Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA)))),
                MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
        videoName.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)));
        videoPath.add(String.valueOf(Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA)))));
        videoThumbnail.add(bmThumbnail);
    }
    cursor.close();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+videoThumbnail.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    VideoAdapter videoAdapter = new VideoAdapter(this, videoName,videoThumbnail);
    videolist.setAdapter(videoAdapter);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Is it possible to display video thumbnails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334694/android-is-it-possible-to-display-video-thumbnails)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951766/creating-thumbnail-from-video-file-returns-null-bitmap/34028554#34028554 is another Thread about this

Comment: Thanks Amir, but it also taking time to get the thumbnail.

Comment: I use Glide As I suggest in links and its work fine

Comment: can you post the code.?

Comment: see my answer , Hope this help you

Comment: Thanks Amir, it's working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following library to your Gradle :

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
```

Then in your code do something like this :

```
Glide.with(context)
                .load(URI_OF_YOUR_VIDEO)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_video_place_holder)
                .into(imageView);
```

It's very smooth and also cache your image.

Answer (score 0):

A common solution for this is to generate the thumbnails one time only, then save them to a file.

Another choice maybe multithreading, but may cause `OutOfMemoryError` if device RAM is low.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Bitmap bitmapThumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(mActivity.getContentResolver(),
     Long.parseLong(video_id), 
     Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, 
     options);
```

FYI

> Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND for 96 x 96
>
> Thumbnails.MINI_KIND for 512 x 384 px

Answer (score 0):

You can create all your `thumnails` in background thread using `AsyncTask` intimating the user that some progress is going on. When all thumbnailing is done then you can do the rest of the work.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this with Glide, but not with Picasso.

```
Glide.with(context)
     .load(im.getUri())
     .into(holder.imageView);
```

(I am using a `RecyclerView`)