# how to get multiple thumbnail from video in android?

Tags: android, video

I have some videos in my sd card and I want to retrieve multiple thumbnail from any video. I used code from [Android: Is it possible to display video thumbnails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334694/android-is-it-possible-to-display-video-thumbnails)
but this returns only one thumbnail, is there any way to retrieve more than one screenshots from a vides, is so then please suggest me, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate multiple thumbnails using ffmpeg
http://blog.prashanthellina.com/2008/03/29/creating-video-thumbnails-using-ffmpeg/

basically you can add ffmpeg lib to your app and then let the lib generate the thumbnail for you.