# I am working on android project where i need to show thumbnail of video from server

Tags: android

I am working on android project where i need to show thumbnail of video from server 
is it possible or not ? if possible please help me

Answer (score 0):

It is possible through one of the two ways:

- either get the thumbnail image from server and display it
- Or get the thumbnail from the video programmatically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2349063/2185634) will help

Answer (score 0):

It is possible yes. First, you need to examine the data structure. Usually, they use JSON or XML which they store the URL of video and thumb with different ID's. If you find the ID of thumbnail and set it to ImageView it should be all sorted.

Best,
Mack.