# How to retrieve the video thumbnail in Android

Tags: android, universal-image-loader, picasso

My sdcard video folder contains number of .mp4 video files.
According to my requirement I want to list down those video files in my android application listview with their **"Thumbnail"** and **"Name"**. BTW I plan to use **Picasso** or **Universal image loader** for image caching. Please tell me anyone know how to do?

Comment: Check out this one :[Android Video Thumbnail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334694/android-is-it-possible-to-display-video-thumbnails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails;
```

You can get two preview thumbnail sizes from the video:

Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND for 96 x 96

Thumbnails.MINI_KIND for 512 x 384 px

use this code

```
String filePath = "/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/my_video.mp4"; //change the location of your file!

ImageView imageview_mini = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_mini);
ImageView imageview_micro = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_micro);

Bitmap bmThumbnail;



bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath, Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
imageview_mini.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);
```

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334694/android-is-it-possible-to-display-video-thumbnails)

Comment: Yes I saw this but i'm expecting Picasso or Universal image loader base code and without using Bitmap objects. Like passing URI directly.