# How to get video thumbnail in android?

Tags: android, android-videoview, video-thumbnails

I am trying to get a thumbnail of a video. But unfortunately i am not able to get thumbnails.

```
        itmap bmThumbnail;

        // MICRO_KIND: 96 x 96 thumbnail
        bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail("file://" + catBean.tempImage,
                MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
        img_icon.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);
```

Comment: look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334694/android-is-it-possible-to-display-video-thumbnails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I create video thumbnail like this in my app

```
 Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathOfFile);
    if(myBitmap == null) {
        myBitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(pathOfFile, Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);

 }
```

Comment: I have tried it, but it didn't work for the videos that are on SD Card (External Storage) on Android 5.0+. It returned null bitmap

Comment: If you get video from sd card, then check first, Is video is in external storage or in some cloud storage. Because if video is on cloud storage, you will receive bitmap null.

Comment: It has nothing to do with cloud.  It is the new Storage Access Framework that screws it up.  This won't work with SD card from Android 5.0

Answer (score 1):

In Xml :

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In java:

```
 long id = ""; //Video Id 

 ImageView thumbnail = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
 ContentResolver crThumb = getContentResolver();
 BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
 options.inSampleSize = 2;
 Bitmap curThumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(crThumb, id,
                            MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, options);
 thumbnail.setImageBitmap(curThumb);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Bitmap bMap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(file.getAbsolutePath(), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
```

and for more details see this [ThumbnailUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html#createVideoThumbnail%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Answer (score 0):

It's not too hard to do. Something like this:

```
int id = **"The Video's ID"**
ImageView iv = (ImageView ) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imagePreview);
ContentResolver crThumb = getContentResolver();
BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 1;
Bitmap curThumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(crThumb, id, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, options);
iv.setImageBitmap(curThumb);
```

See more about MediaStore at: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Video.html

Answer (score 0):

The following code runs perfectly:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(file.getAbsolutePath(), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
```

If you do not go through **CURSOR** or If you have only **PATH or FILE OBJECTS**, you can use :

```
 public static Bitmap createVideoThumbnail (String filePath, int kind)
```

Reference : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html#createVideoThumbnail%28java.lang.String,%20int%29