# Android - Thumbnail from video file

Tags: java, android, video, mediastore

I currently have a app where the user click on the floating action button and selects a video file, the file is then saved to a different folder. I want to then show thumbnails of all the video's. I've seen a tutorial series where it is done with MediaStore, but then I can't set the path of the uri.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Here is my class to open the gallery and save the video to a different path:

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int pick = 100;
    Uri videoUri;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            openGallery();
            }
        });
    }

    private void openGallery() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, pick);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == pick) {
            try
            {
                Log.e("videopath","videopath");
                AssetFileDescriptor videoAsset = getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(data.getData(), "r");
                FileInputStream fis = videoAsset.createInputStream();
                File root=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"MYFOLDER");

                if (!root.exists()) {
                    root.mkdirs();
                }

                File file;
                file=new File(root,"android_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".mp4" );

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                while ((len = fis.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    fos.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
                fis.close();
                fos.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            videoUri = data.getData();
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334694/android-is-it-possible-to-display-video-thumbnails

Comment: See this: http://androidsrc.net/create-thumbnail-video-android-application/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `ThumbnailUtils` class in Android for this purpose.

```
public static Bitmap createVideoThumbnail (String filePath, int kind)
```

this method returns a bitmap of the video.

- First parameter is the filepath, ie the location of the video file to be passed as String.
- Second parameter is the kind of bitmap that you need, there are two types:

  - `MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND` which generates thumbnail of size 96 x 96
  - `MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND` which generates thumbnail of size 512 x 384.

**Eg:**

```
Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath, Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

Here is the API docs for further info[[Here]](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html).

Comment: which location does this thumbnail get saved to? I would like to upload it onto a server.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do it with `Glide` :

```
Glide.with(context).load(videoPath).asBitmap().into(imageView);
```